# Solarized color definitions in vimrc file

Tags: vim, colors, vimrc

The solarized theme defines some base colors and assigns those to variables, as seen [here](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/blob/master/colors/solarized.vim#L226).

I would like to know how I can use these color definitions in my `.vimrc` file.
Currently, I use pathogen to load solarized and it is loaded with a simple `syntax enabled` and `colorscheme solarized`, but when I want to reference e.g. `s:base00` in my `.vimrc` file, I get an error:

```
E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermfg=s:base00
```

Comment: "an error" is not very useful. Please state the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermfg=s:base00

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems:

- The `:highlight` command does not evaluate `ctermfg` values as expressions. It accepts only a literal color number, or a color name (see `:help cterm-colors`). You get E421 because `s:base00` is not a number, nor a valid color name.

  You could use `execute 'highlight GroupName ctermfg=' . s:base00` to build an command string and execute it (this is basically what `colors/solarized.vim` does); however there is an additional problem.
- Variables that start with `s:` are script-local variables (see `:help s:var`), so they are not accessible in your `.vimrc` (or anywhere except the script in which they are defined: `colors/solarized.vim`).

  The defining script “exports” the color values as a part of the highlight groups that it defines, but does not seem to export the individual cterm/gui values it uses for each Solarized color. If you want to create your own highlight group that uses these values, then you will probably have to edit it into your copy of `colors/solarized.vim` (though you may want to use `s:fg_base00`/`s:bg_base00` instead of `s:base00` since the former cover `guifg` vs. `ctermfg` so that your group would automatically work on both GUIs and terminals).